# With python type hints, how can I tell *why* something doesn't match?

Tags: python, types

Let's say I have code like this

```py
class DemoType(TypedDict):
    firstName: str
    lastName: str
    email: str
    age: int


def returns_demo_type() -> DemoType:
    return {
        "firstName": "hello",
        "lastName": "world",
        "email": "foo@example.com",
        "age": "old",
    }
```

This is wrong because "age" is a string instead of a number. And my IDE (intelliJ) turns it a very ugly yellow for me.  But the error message is `Expected type 'DemoType', got 'dict[str, str]' instead` , and that doesn't help me narrow down the problem very well.

What tooling can I use to solve this problem? **I'd like it to tell me more specifically that the type of 'age' is wrong**. mypy seems to have similar output, but maybe I don't know how to use mypy. Right now I'm staring at my types and trying to figure out what I screwed up, but there has to be a better way.

Edit: **If age is an int then the typing is happy as-is**

Comment: What else do you want to know?

Comment: You should return an actual DemoType, not something that accidentally has the same structure.

Comment: when do you get that message? if you run `type(returns_demo_type())` you see it's a dict class and it's not a str

Comment: @luk2302 Hm I was using TypedDict because I have all these big dicts and I wanted some protection on what their keys are suppose to be.  I guess I could refactor that to not be literal dicts anymore but that's not ideal.

Comment: @eshirvana I get it on mouseover in the IDE or on running mypy.  What I want is for it to say like "Expected type DemoType. Key 'age' is int, got str`

Comment: Have you considered using dataclasses instead?

Comment: The point is that *even if you had a valid value for the `"age"` key*, the thing you're `return`ing would *still* just be an ordinary `dict` (with a type that your IDE might infer as something like `dict[str, Any]` or `dict[str, Union[str, int]]`), not an instance of `DemoType`. If you want one of those, you have to construct it. The return type annotation does not cause any kind of type coercion; it is **only** a *hint* to *external, static* type checking utilities like your IDE. `def x() -> int: return 'hi mom'` is perfectly legal Python, and it runs without exception, returning the string.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm pretty sure you can instantiate a TypedDict like a normal dict. It's in the spec https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/   -- i can't do newlines in comments, can i?   But there's a class B(TypedDict): and b: B = {'x': 0} in there, and my IDE/mypy see it as a DemoType when all the keys are correct.

Comment: Your IDE and type checker see it that way, but Python doesn't care. `type(B)` will still be `dict`. I misspoke/misunderstood in the previous comment, though (I don't normally use these features). `type(b)` will still be `dict` *even if* you explicitly do `b: B = B({'x': 0})`. ...But then, I guess that isn't really relevant to the problem you're asking about. Never mind.